# MySQL Where being ignored

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know why the published index is being ignored in this query?

```
SELECT news.id, news.slug, news.title, news.created_on FROM (news) 
WHERE `published` = '1' 
AND news.title LIKE '%running%' 
OR news.body LIKE '%running%' 
OR news.intro LIKE '%running%' 
ORDER BY created_on desc
```

Comment: can you post your table structure?

Comment: Not sure if it would affect the optimization, but the query logic (and the perceived desired outcome) seems to me as if it would need parentheses around the "OR'd" clauses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume that the ORs are causing it.
Try parenthesis around the three statements that are OR connected.

Like this:

```
SELECT news.id, news.slug, news.title, news.created_on FROM (news) 
WHERE `published` = '1' 
AND (
     news.title LIKE '%running%' 
  OR news.body LIKE '%running%' 
  OR news.intro LIKE '%running%' 
)
ORDER BY created_on desc
```